# Foreach solo toma el ultimo objeto

Tags: html, jquery

Obtengo el valor de un input para hacer aparecer y desaparecer un div según la opción que se elija. aquí la idea es que al seleccionar cualquiera de las opciones a excepción de la primera el div #precio se desaparezca.

```js
$('#pago').focusout(function() {
 var x = $(this).val();
 var metod_pay = ['Credit Card','Debit Card','Paypal','Wire Transfer'];
                 
    metod_pay.forEach(pay => {
    if( x == pay ){                   
         $("#precio").css("display", "none");
    }
 else{
  $("#precio").css("display", "block");
 }
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
 <input class="custom-select col-12" id="pago" name="pay_mode" placeholder="--Select Pay Mode--" list="browsersss" autocomplete="off" required="required">
  <datalist id="browsersss">                              
    <option value="Efectivo">Efectivo</option>                                   
    <option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>                                   
    <option value="Debit Card">Debit Card</option>                                   
    <option value="Wire Transfer">Wire Transfer</option>                                   
    <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>                                 </datalist>
</div>
 <div id="precio"> <input type="text"> </div>
```

pero solo está seleccionando el último objeto 'Wire Transfer' si selecciono 'paypal', el div debería seguir oculto pero no es el caso.

Comment: Qué tal si en el condicional que tienes dentro del foreach pones: `if(x[pay] == pay)...`

Comment: El problema que el `foreach` sigue ejecutandose, y siempre acabará con un `block`, exceptuando en el caso del último elemento del array. Es decir, si selecciono `Credit card`, la primera vez hara un `none` pero luego volerá a ponerse `block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes cambiar el `foreach` por un `if`.

```
if(metod_pay.includes(x)){
   $("#precio").css("display", "none");
}else{
   $("#precio").css("display", "block");
}
```

Comment: me funciono a la perfeccion, muchas gracias